# How to map java servlet with action form by using @WebServlet?

Tags: jsp

Since we dont need to have the web.xml in Servlet 3.0, then how can we use @WebServlet correctly (Assume that I have two servlet classes reside in different packages, and two action forms resided in two different folders)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servlet API 3.0 introduces annotations to simplify deployment.In `javax.servlet.annotation`package we have `@WebServlet`: which defines a servlet component.

The web application deployment descriptor `web.xml` has become optional in Servlet 3.0. Instead, the container at run time will process the annotations of the classes in WEB-INF/classes.

Now the question comes how does the container knows which class to process.
As you asked suppose there are two servlets.
`src/mypackage1/ServletOne` and `src/mypackage2/ServletTwo` and the Servlet class definations are like

```
@WebServlet("/servletOne")
public class ServletOne extends HttpServlet { ...... }
```

and

```
@WebServlet("/servletTwo")
public class ServletTwo extends HttpServlet { ...... }
```

When these classes are compiled it will be stored as `.class` in the following hierarchy

`build/classes/mypackage1/ServletOne.class`

and

`build/classes/mypackage2/ServletTwo.class`

When the container sees the `annotation` above the class-defination it will check for the `.class` files in the specified folder and it resolves the call for the required Servlet

Comment: Then how about the action forms? Will do I need to specify the package path to the servlet? For example, <form action="mypackage1/servletOne> and <form action="mypackage2/servletTwo> or I just simply do <form action="servletOne">?

Comment: `<form action="servletOne method="post">`  when you hit the submit button the container then searches for the url pattern in the annotation and rest works like what I said